# Angular2 making multiple requests using rxjs subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an angular2 app that adds or removes items from a multiple select box and sends each item to a remote api individually to be added to be processed in the database.  The following method sends the request to the server and gets a response as an observable

```
removeFromClientLibrary(username: string, roleID: string): Observable<any> {
        let body = JSON.stringify({Key: username, Value: roleID});

        return this._http.post(this._removeFromLibraryURL, body, this.emsConfig.getStandardHttpHeaders())
            .map((res:Response) => <any>res.json());
    }
```

Then I have added a client to consume this, by using the subscribe method to consume it.  My understanding is that it is only necessary to call subscribe once, however, I can't seem to get this to work.  The only thing that returns the proper result is to loop through each item and subscribe multiple times:

```
for (let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
  this._accountsService.removeFromClientLibrary(this.username, selected[i].RoleID)
    .subscribe(status => {          
      console.log(status);
    });
}
```

Is there a way to consume the results of the api using rxjs without subscribing multiple times as above, or is that the only way to retrieve the data?

Comment: So you want to be notified only once what all the `this._accountsService.removeFromClientLibrary` calls complete?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`combineLatest` operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md).

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  selected.map(selectedId =>
    this._accountsService.removeFromClientLibrary(this.username, selected[i].RoleID)))
)
  .subscribe((statusArray) => console.log('all done: ', statusArray));
```